# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am receiving the following error:

```
 Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in  line 48
```

Below is line 48

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_email, $user_pass);
```

Below is a larger portion of the code

```
   // Using mysql_real_escape_string to ensure that the statements are legal SQL statements that can be stored
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);


      /*

        Using Prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection

      */


      //  Create a perepared statement 
     if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * from admins WHERE user_email=? AND user_pass=?")) {


        // Bind the paramaters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $password);


        // Execute the query
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


        /*

         Usually we would bind the result to be able to retrieve their given value
         However, in this case we are not interested in retrieving values from the database

        */
           /* fetch value */
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);


        /* bind result variables */
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_email, $user_pass);

         echo $user_email;
```

The connection is properly established and even without condition set in the myqsli_prepare query i still retrieve the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at select you are selecting more than 2 columns and only bind 2 in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`, in other words the numbers of columns in select must be the same number of variables in `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`

To fix, change

```
SELECT * from admins WHERE user_email=? AND user_pass=?
```

To:

```
SELECT user_mail, user_pass from admins WHERE user_email=? AND user_pass=?"
```